# Experiment on Qualtrics, simple OLS or Panel with fixed effects?

Tags: least-squares, panel-data, experiment-design, fixed-effects-model

I ran an experiment that led to the following dataset

```
id x    q1    q2    q3    q4 ... q8
1  0.1  20    40    30    60
2  0.4  30    30    40    50
3  0.3  60    90    100   100
4  0.1  20    40    30    60
5  0.0  3     0     43    60
6  0.3  60    90    100   75
.
.
221
```

Basically I want to assess how x affected q1...q8 given that x was randomized across individuals and displayed before they answered q1-q8 (where q1-q8 are all in the same format 0-100 and measuring the same thing on different objects: In this case "q" is a news and I ask individuals to state their perceived credibility of the news from 0 to 100)

so what I did was a simple OLS using the mean of q1, q2... q8 as my dependent variable and x as my independent. Doing this I get significant results and it all makes sense

however, I was also considering to look at the problem from another perspective making my dataset a panel of this type:

```
id  x   measure    q   
1  0.1    20       q1  
1  0.1    40       q2
1  0.1    30       q3
....     ...       ...
2  0.4    30       q1
2  0.4    30       q2
.
.
221
```

so basically I was thinking to regress "measure" on x using two fixed effects, ID fixed effect and "q" fixed effect (using dummies for id'ss and q's), although, if I do this all the coefficients are shrinked to zero and it doesn't make much sense and I don't understand why this is happening... maybe I should not include these fixed effects? or maybe I should just stick to the first model that is already significant and makes sense?

can anybody explain me why I get this?

thank you in advance.

Comment: what about question (and id ) as a random effect?

Comment: OLS has problem. You analyzed re-generated variable, mean of q1 - q8, instead of original variables. Second approach is OK, but need to treat id's effect as random effect, instead of fixed. In addition, maybe difference (effect) of q also needed to be treated as random.

Comment: @seanv507 , i'm not 100% sure, but I was thinking about it.. given that x does not vary from q1 to q8 for the same individual, woldn't any random effect (/fixed effect) for ID capture all the variation of the dependent variable that would be associated with x? Because after I didn't get any result, I was wondering if this was the case! So I manipulated the data to test if it was like this, increasing or decreasing q1, q2.q8 according to the corresponding x of the individual. Even doing this x resulted non significant and this looks surprising as I explicetly manipulated the data!